# Retrieving start and end point coordinates with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, point

How do I retrieve start and end point coordinates with ArcPy for a polyline feature class?

I expect to pass a segment identifier to a subroutine and have it pass back start and end coordinates. The Field Calculator method doesn't work for me, because I need the value for other calculations that can't be performed within it. (I also prefer not to change the data to store these coordinates as attributes.) I am attempting to calculate address ranging for a "center out" addressing scheme. The address value depends on the distance to the "county center".

Answer (score 15):

The process for this seems to have changed between ArcGIS 10.0 and 10.1.  I will include a sample for both.

Here is the help document on reading geometries in 10.1 using arcpy:  [Reading Geometries 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Reading_geometries/002z0000001t000000/)
This document discusses the parameters for a Polyline geometry type:  [Polyline (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Polyline/018z00000008000000/)

**10.1**

```
import arcpy

infc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# Enter for loop for each feature
#
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc, ["OID@", "SHAPE@"]):
    # Print the current line ID

    print("Feature {0}:".format(row[0]))

    #Set start point
    startpt = row[1].firstPoint

    #Set Start coordinates
    startx = startpt.X
    starty = startpt.Y

    #Set end point
    endpt = row[1].lastPoint

    #Set End coordinates
    endx = endpt.X
    endy = endpt.Y
```

**10.0**

Here is the help document on reading geometries in 10.0 using arcpy:  [Reading Geometries 10.0](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Reading_geometries/002z0000001t000000/)
This document discusses the parameters for a Geometry object:  [Geometry](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Geometry/000v00000095000000/)

```
import arcpy

infc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# Identify the geometry field
#
desc = arcpy.Describe(infc)
shapefieldname = desc.ShapeFieldName

# Create search cursor
#
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(infc)

# Enter for loop for each feature/row
#
for row in rows:
    # Create the geometry object
    #
    feat = row.getValue(shapefieldname)

    # Print the current line ID
    #
    print "Feature %i:" % row.getValue(desc.OIDFieldName)

    #Set start point
    startpt = feat.firstPoint

    #Set Start coordinates
    startx = startpt.X
    starty = startpt.Y

    #Set end point
    endpt = feat.lastPoint

    #Set End coordinates
    endx = endpt.X
    endy = endpt.Y
```

The difference between the two basically lies in how you access the feature geometry.  There have been some shortcuts added in **10.1** to make it easier to get to the geometry object.

Answer (score 6):

I have done this before and prefer to use a Search Cursor and read the geometry. It creates a loop and allows you to do calcs on each shape.

```
inFeatures = "Feature"
shapeName = arcpy.Describe (inFeatures).shapeFieldName
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inFeatures)
for row in rows:
    feat = row.getValue(shapeName)
    xy1 = feat.firstPoint
    xy2 = feat.lastPoint
```

That loop allows you to add some calculations with it and go shape by shape.

There is some extra help in the Help: [Working with geometry in Python](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001s000000)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the firstPoint and lastPoint properties of the [Polyline](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000008000000) object.