# Adding end nodes to a line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, point, line

I'm hoping someone can help me here.

I have a line feature and what I am trying to achieve is to determine is in which direction the line ends.

I understand that this could be achieved with 'Feature Vertices to Points' to determine start and end nodes in ArcGIS Info, however I only have ArcEditor.

Are there any alternative ways to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help guys,

ps. I'm using ArcEditor 10.1 & I have QGIS.

Comment: There is a programmatic solution here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/31687/8104

Comment: This is just an aside but the ArcEditor license level only existed prior to 10.1 so I think you will be using a Standard level license now - Help | About ArcMap should clarify that for you.

Comment: Thanks guys.I will look into these suggestions and come back with more questions I'm sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can also visualize this by clicking your line symbology in the Table of Contents. Under the Esri line styles, select the symbology called "Arrow at End" and this will show you the directionality of the line.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to SEE where the line ends, you can also add an arrow symbol at the end of your line. (layer properties > symbology >symbol properties > cartographic line symbol > line properties).

Otherwise, for a non programmatic solution, you can compute the X and Y coordinates of the end point based on "calculate geometry"(right click on field), then you add XY event data to see your points.