# Changing sequence of point features into order along line using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, point, fields-attributes, sorting

The picture below shows that the order of attribute record for point features is different to their actually distributed location.

How can I change or sort the attribute records into a proper order by using Python for ArcGIS?

There also a line under the point features.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this using linear referencing:

- Turn the line into a route.
- Use the points to add measures along that route as an event table.
- Then read the order of those points (now point events) in the event table from top to bottom.

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple approaches.Try this ,

1. Get the starting point of the poly-line feature
2. Get the nearest vertex from the point feature
3. Create an empty point feature class and push this nearest point into that
4. perform 2,3 recursively for all points in the point feature class

A clean and elegant way to get first point of a polyline is found in [How do I retrieve start and end point coordinates with Python/arcpy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31684/how-do-i-retrieve-start-and-end-point-coordinates-with-python-arcpy)

There is Near Analysis for calculating nearest vertex.Refer the examples in ESRI [link](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00080000001q000000)